# WPF progress bars not updating correctly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a window that shows some activities todo and each activity has a progress bar that has to progress accordingly while the time an activity require to be completed, is passing.
I'm using a dispatcher timer for this but i'm struggling with the logic, so i get weird behaviours, like bars filling up correctly 4 times and then they are always immediately at 100%.

This is the code in my control:

```
 private void InitializeDispatcherTimer()
        {
            var dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);

            dispatcherTimer.Start();
            WhenTimerStarted = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var activity in ViewModel.Activities)
            {
                var mySeconds = DateTime.Now.Subtract(WhenTimerStarted).TotalSeconds;

                if (activity.duration != null)
                {
                    var myDurationInSeconds = (Double)activity.Duration.Value.TotalSeconds;
                    activity.Progress = (mySeconds * 100) / myDurationInSeconds;

                }

                if (activity.Progress == 100)
                {
                    WhenTimerStarted = DateTime.Now;
                }


            }
        }
```

This is the bar in the xaml file:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progress" Grid.Row="3" Value="{Binding Path=Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Maximum="100"/>
```

The ViewModel.Activities is a an array of 4 ActivityViewModel, so each activity is a view model.
When an activity is completed, in another class i have an event called Activity_Done() where i set the activity.Progress to zero, so the bars get emptied.

I supposed the problem is in the variable mySeconds, becasue as the timer run and time pass, it's get bigger and bigger, so dividing for myDurationInSeconds will give large results (?) and i dont know where to reset it, or i am confusing the purpose of dispatcherTimer.Interval in relation with the duration and the remaining time of each activity.
Or i just need to rethink the Tick logic, in which case, i would glady accept some tips.

Also i need to mention that the program is being fed with a supply of activities to complete untill i stop it or close the app.

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Value Binding is pointless. It only has an effect on TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: thanks, will fix that

Comment: Besides that, it is unclear how your logic is supposed to work. It seems you are resetting WhenTimerStarted as soon as any activity reaches 100%. Also the comparison to exactly 100 seems dangerous. Better ckeck `if (activity.Progress >= 100)`.

Comment: The point is, each time an activity is done, it gets eliminated and a new one comes up and is started, so the bars have to be setted back to 0 and progress with a new duration (durations are random, generated when an activity is pushed to the queue)